# Haskell update parameters

Tags: haskell

I wanted to try something new, so I've decided to wrap my head around Haskell. Coming from a mainly C#/Java background, I have a question about updating various values. I've managed to narrow it down to a single problem. Consider the following function:

```
appendHistory :: State -> Action -> State
appendHistory (State gs p1 p2 h) a = State gs p1 p2 (a : h)
```

This basically appends the action to the state's history. `gs`, `p1` and `p2` are rather irrelevant in this case, since we're trying to update `h`. For the sake of copying the variables they need to be named (so I can use them on the right hand side of `=`). Is there any way I can write `appendHistory`, so that `h` gets updated without having to specify `gs`, `p1` and `p2` explicitly?

One option would be to let other functions handle retrieving and updating state. `appendHistory` now doesn't have to specify the other parameters. Not my faviorite, as we've just moved our problem to `updateHistory`. In Haskell:

```
appendHistory :: State -> Action -> State
appendHistory s a = updateHistory s (a : (history s))

history :: State -> History
history (State _ _ _ h) = h

updateHistory :: State -> History -> State
updateHistory (State s p1 p2 _) h = State s p1 p2 h
```

Another way would be to use records. But I've been told (/read) that name clashes might occur when using the same names. I think I'm going to have a lot of records with fieldname `state`, so I've been avoiding those for the moment.

I guess, all I want to do is (non-functionally):

```
void Update(State state, Action action) {
    state.history.append(action);
}
```

Is there a way to do this 'nicely' in Haskell, without having to write a 'getter' and a 'setter' for every `data` parameter?

---

For full reference:

```
type History = [Action]
type Deck = [Card]
type Hand = [Card]
type Graveyard = [Card]

data Card = Card -- Still to expand

data PlayerState = PlayerState Hand Deck Graveyard
data GameState = NotStarted | Playing | Finished

data State = State GameState PlayerState PlayerState History
```

`Action`s are just definitions on how to mutate `State`.

Comment: This is exactly the sort of thing lenses are used for.

Comment: I suggest you look into Record Syntax, as it allows you to do just that. I currently don't have time to write up a full answer, but you should also include the definition of `State` if you want a complete answer.

Comment: So that pushes me to records in both cases? I'll add a definition for `State`, although I would've thought that it wouldnt matter if it was either an `Integer` or something more complex.

Comment: If you use lenses you don't have to use records, although it makes defining the lenses easier.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the pointers, both of you. Feel free to add an answer so I can accept it, or mark it as a duplicate if it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As melpomene commented, [lenses](http://lens.github.io/) are the modern standard answer to your question. You can define lenses manually

```
{-# LANGUAGE Rank2Types, TypeFamilies #-}
import Control.Lens

gameHistory :: Lens' State History
gameHistory = lens (\(State _ _ _ h) -> h)
                   (\(State gs p1 p2 _) h -> State gs p1 p2 h)
```

...or let Template Haskell do it for you

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
data State = State {
        _gameState :: GameState
      , _player₀State, _player₁State :: PlayerState
      , _gameHistory :: History }
makeLenses ''State
```

which automatically creates

```
gameState :: Lens' State GameState
player₀State :: Lens' State GameState
player₁State :: Lens' State GameState
gameHistory :: Lens' State History
```

Once you have such a lens, you can use the [operators](https://github.com/ekmett/lens/wiki/Operators) for tweaking `State` objects:

```
appendHistory :: Action -> State -> State -- more conventional argument order in Haskell
appendHistory a = gameHistory %~ (a:)
```

Comment: These lenses shrunk my codebase by half :)